# Unable to find the input tab to provide the path for luxrender in blender 2.74

Tags: rendering

I'm pretty much new to LuxRender engine. I was trying to install LuxRender version 1.4 into Blender 2.74. But many tutorials out there seems to suggest that you need to provide the path to LuxRender after installing the same as addon. They also showed a screenshot where you need to enter the path in Blender 2.5x but I couldn't find anything like that in Blender 2.74 . ..  Kindly help me out.

I have attached screen shot in Blender 2.5x below. . .
[image]

I have also attached the screenshot in Blender 2.74 below. . . .

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find it in the "Blender User Preferences" in the Addons tab, under the plugin *Render:LuxRender*.
[image: User Preferences showing the LuxRender addon]